# TrimStart/ForEach on multiple lines

Tags: powershell

I'm new to learning PowerShell and I've been writing code to do the following:

1. Import a list of computers from a CSV file
2. Rename the computer from its old name in the file to the new name in the file
3. Grab the currently logged on user on each computer that got renamed
4. Trim off the beginning part of the user name ("CompanyName\")
5. Add "@company.com" to the end of the line
6. Set that data to a variable
7. Use that variable as an email address in a programmatic email
8. Send said email

Right now, I have it outputting the results of 4 & 5 to a text file and then importing it via **Get-Content**, but this doesn't work, as if the file doesn't already exist, it won't work.  It can't seem to output the file then grab the contents from it.  I'm thinking there must be some way to do it, but I'm not sure.

I think I'm not looping the **TrimStart** and **For-Each** command properly.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
$Import = Import-CSV Rename.csv -Header OldName, NewName
    ForEach ( $Machine in $Import ) {Rename-Computer -ComputerName $Machine.OldName -NewName $Machine.NewName -DomainCredential $Cred -whatif -Verbose}
$a = ForEach ( $User in $MachineList ){
    (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $User.OldName -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class Win32_ComputerSystem)[0].UserName;
    }
$b = $a.TrimStart("CompanyName\") | ForEach {$_+'@Company.com'} | Out-File names.txt
$Address = Get-Content names.txt 
ForEach ($line in $Address) {
    $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
    $Mail.To = "$Address"
    $Mail.Subject = "Please restart your computer"
    $Mail.HTMLBody = Get-Content RenameComputerEmail.htm
    $Mail.Send()
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why `Out-File` doesn't work, but I would suggest an approach like the one below. Be aware that I have not used `outlook.application` before, so I can't guarantee that the code works without tweaking.

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
$Import = Import-CSV Rename.csv -Header OldName, NewName

$Addresses = @()

#Rename each computer and get the username
ForEach ( $Machine in $Import ) {
    $Comp = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $User.OldName -Class "Win32_ComputerSystem"
    $Usermail = "$($Comp.UserName.Split("\")[-1])@Company.com"
    $Addresses += $Usermail

    Rename-Computer -ComputerName $Machine.OldName -NewName $Machine.NewName -DomainCredential $Cred -whatif -Verbose
    #Don't bother saving the names and then reloading. (unless it's for logging)
} 

#Create one instance of outlook
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application

#Send mails to each address
ForEach ($address in $Addresses) {
    $Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
    $Mail.To = "$address"
    $Mail.Subject = "Please restart your computer"
    $Mail.HTMLBody = (Get-Content RenameComputerEmail.htm) -join "`n"
    $Mail.Send()
}

#Disposing the outlook object using all the methods just to be safe.
$Outlook.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Mail)
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Outlook)
```

Comment: I had to get rid of the "quit Outlook" section, but otherwise this looks great.  The `Outlook.application` works just fine.  I'd like to use the `Send-Mail`, but the company isn't set up with a SMTP server.

Combining the get username and rename computer into one `ForEach` loop is definitely the way I wanted it to go, I just wasn't sure how to.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Np, I updated the quit methods. Why did you need to remove them? When using Office ComObjects you need to release the objects properly. If not, the process and some handles might still be running, and that may cause your weird issues. Check out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730962.aspx

Comment: Mainly because I always have Outlook open when I'm at work (and this is running in my account), so running the script with the close commands made my Outlook shutdown.


If I was running this from a service account, I'd definitely keep it in.


Maybe just leave the `[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Mail)` in?

Comment: Ahh. Then Outlook is different from excel etc. I never tried, but I guess it only supports one instance at a time and grabs a handle for your open instance(proccess). With Word, Excel etc. it opens a separate proccess for the comobject, so then you need to close it. :) Could you test skipping the `quit()`-line but keep the rest. If it works, it would at least clear some of the handles from COM.

Comment: Yeah, Outlook only opens one instance of itself normally.  Usually only time I see multiple instances is when the process doesn't start properly.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a few recommendations that should help you with your script writing.

### Variable Naming

Try naming your variables something that is self-descriptive. That will make troubleshooting easier, when you're debugging and stepping through your code line-by-line.

### Writing Code

Write your code step-by-step. Don't try to bite off too much at one time. If you document your code with in-line comments, it will help it make more sense to you.

### Parameter Names

Use the parameter names any time you are writing a script, and don't take the positional parameters for granted. This will improve the script's readability.

### Filesystem Paths

Qualify all of your filesystem paths. You never know when your "working directory" might be different from the directory where your script resides. Use the `$PSScriptRoot` variable (first introduced in PowerShell v3.0), to reference the "*containing folder of your script file.*"

### Solution

I haven't tested this code below, since I don't have a copy of your CSV file, but it should help you understand what's going on a bit more. I've also taken the liberty of consolidating some of the code to make it simpler.

**Important**: Make sure you're running the latest version of PowerShell, which is version 4.0. 3.0 would be an acceptable alternative, but anything older than that is fairly restrictive as far as features go. You can determine the version you're running by typing `$PSVersionTable`.

```
#requires -version 3.0

# 1. Get administrative credential
$Cred = Get-Credential;

# 2. Import the CSV file
$Import = Import-CSV -Path $PSScriptRoot\Rename.csv -Header OldName, NewName;

# 3. Rename each computer
$Import | % { Rename-Computer -ComputerName $PSItem.OldName -NewName $PSItem.NewName -DomainCredential $Cred -WhatIf -Verbose; };

# 4. Get username from each, remote computer, and write to names.txt
$Import.OldName | ForEach-Object -Process { (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $PSItem -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName.TrimStart('CompanyName\') + '@companyname.com'; } | Out-File -FilePath $PSScriptRoot\names.txt;

# 5. Get all of the usernames
$Address = Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\names.txt;

# 6. Send e-mail to each user
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application;
ForEach ($line in $Address) {
    $Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
    $Mail.To = "$Address"
    $Mail.Subject = "Please restart your computer"
    $Mail.HTMLBody = Get-Content RenameComputerEmail.htm
    $Mail.Send()
    }
```

Comment: With a big enough list, that would probably A: crash, or B: eat up all your resources. You're creating an instance of Outlook for each mail. :)

Comment: I didn't write the original code. I modified some of the parts of the code that I thought would be more confusing to a first-time user of PowerShell. Good point, nonetheless.

Comment: Wasn't blaming you, just making a point when you were first fixing it :) +1 on the PS3+ recommandation. If only Windows Update would fix this for us with a critical update...

Comment: Thanks to all for the tips.  I started batch scripting to automate a bunch of job functions, so I know the value of commenting your scripts.  I've done some simple PS scripts before (get AD membership, copy AD groups from one user to another, etc.), but this is my first involved script.

Between the tips here and @FrodeF.'s code, this should really help me get better in PS.